# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have the following code:

```
dgv.DataSource = myObject.functionthatreturnsadatatable()
dgv.Columns(0).Visible = False
dgv.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Something"
dgv.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Something"
dgv.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Something"
dgv.Columns(4).Visible = False
dgv.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Something"
dgv.Columns(6).HeaderText = "Something"
dgv.AutoResizeColumns()
Debug.WriteLine(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)
```

This is on my formLoad event and I keep getting this error even if my dgv is no empty.
If I comment the last line, the code works and my dgv is filled. What have I done wrong?

Comment: At what point in this is a row selected? You're referencing 'CurrentRow'.  Are you assuming the CurrentRow is the first row (i.e., Row 0) until either the program or user selects a different one?

Comment: Have you figured this out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The DataGridViewRow that represents the row containing the current
>   cell, or Nothing if there is no current cell.

You asked for a cell when the currentRow is nothing.

[MSDN Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

As long as you set `dgv.Columns(0).Visible = False` and you do

`Debug.WriteLine(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)` you will always get that error ..

Comment: From what I have read Its true that you can't access value from an hidden column of ASP.net Gridview, but you can access value from an hidden column of Datagridview. Are you sure you have tested that?

Comment: I confirm. Problem is that currentRow is null, not related to column visibility.

Comment: Yes I have tested. Your test is wrong... He has no error when he comments the last line, Because he does not refer to CurrentRow somewhere else!

Comment: @Chris .. I dont know .. this is so useless for me .. and I couldn't know you test it or just thinkin .. whatever ..